# Header Part disappears when browser window resized

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem creating responsive design of my website. When I resize my browser window to specific width the header dissapers and only body part shows up. Here is the link to my blog website: http://alpha1.dentalblog.az/home/ when resized it won't show you the menu and header logo part. (tablet size or mobile size). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `responsive.css`, you have this style:

```
.hidden-phone{
  display:none !important;
}
```

Specifically called when the page is less than `767px`.

Line 180 you need to remove or change.

Comment: It worked partially but now logo and my banner-ads doesn't show up. If I will use the same logic I guess it will work.

Comment: `<span12>` holds the upper banner, where `<div class="preheader">` is located, I can't seem to find how to show them.

Comment: Check in any media queries in `responsive.css` and look for any `display:none;` where `max-width:767px;`. @BatyrAtamamedov

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot! I changed every single element in 767px media from `display: none` to `display: block;`